# Counting Objects in a noised Image

Tags: python, image-processing

I have this Original-Image:
[image: Original-Image]
And my Task is to count those Peppercorns.
I managed to remove the Noise and the Grid, but at counting those Corns im Stuck. There are 3 pairs, that are so close to each other, that my Program cant count them. Can u help me with it? Thats my attempt:
[image: My Attempt]
In The last 2, i tried to erode/Open those corns with that code:

```
thresh = filters.threshold_minimum(orig_img_no_grid)
img_eroded = morphology.binary_erosion(orig_img_no_grid < thresh, iterations=7)
img_opened = morphology.binary_closing(img_eroded, iterations=4)
```

[image: Missing Corns]
But those marked corns make Problems. The One in the bottom i think i solved with enough erosions, but the other 3? If i erode more, some corns will vanish

Edit: The no Grid image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LVY0.png

Comment: or try some local maxima/minima detection (constructable from erosion/dilation and equality comparison) -- or maybe watershed... works to separate coins that touch, so it probably does something useful here too, but maybe the amount of erosion you mentioned will cause issues with that

Comment: This is a very common problem in particle counting. You will find many texts advising the watershed algorithm to separate them. But this methods raises other difficulties. I would recommend to detect the touching grains by contouring and discriminate 1) by area, 2) by non-roundness. This is workable for two touching grains. It becomes challenging for more.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Any hint on how i do it? I tried many non-OpenCV-Watershed Tutorials/Instructions but i didnt get any to work for me. We had Watershed in the Lecture, but just the Theory. I dont know right now where to start the detection, im still new to this

Comment: could you post the last picture (the grayscale one, no-grid) without the red circles and axes, as data to experiment with?

Comment: added it @ChristophRackwitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i forgot it, here my solution in pure python-Code (Plus it already got corrected, so i dont run in the danger, that he sees this and thinks, i copied that from another User):

```py
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import filters, feature, measure, color
import numpy as np
import tifffile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter, morphology
from scipy.fft import fftfreq, fft2, fftshift, ifft2, ifftshift
from skimage.segmentation import watershed

plt.rcParams["image.cmap"] = "gray"
plt.rcParams["text.color"] = "white"
plt.rcParams["xtick.color"] = "gray"
plt.rcParams["ytick.color"] = "gray"

def fourier_spectrum_to_log_spectrum(im): # reduce max and min values with logarithm
    return np.log10(1 + np.abs(im) ** 2)

def make_notch(first_shape, locations, sigma): # implemented from exercise.ipynb from moodle and slightly modified
    u = fftfreq(first_shape, 1 / first_shape)
    u, v = np.meshgrid(u, u)
    res = np.zeros((first_shape, first_shape))
    for (v_0, u_0) in locations:
        diff = [(v-v_0), (u-u_0)]
        sums = [(v+v_0), (u+u_0)]
        res += np.exp(-(diff[0]  ** 2 + diff[1] ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
        res += np.exp(-(sums[0]  ** 2 + sums[1] ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
        res += np.exp(-(sums[0]  ** 2 + diff[1] ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
        res += np.exp(-(diff[0]  ** 2 + sums[1] ** 2) / (2 * sigma ** 2))
    return res

orig_img = tifffile.imread('input.tif')
orig_img_filtered = median_filter(orig_img, 6)

orig_fft = fftshift(fft2(orig_img_filtered))
orig_fft_log = fourier_spectrum_to_log_spectrum(orig_fft)

brightness_threshold = 10
sigma = 20
highpass_filter = 1 - make_notch(orig_fft.shape[0], [np.array(orig_fft.shape) / 2], sigma)
bright_pixels = morphology.binary_dilation((fourier_spectrum_to_log_spectrum(orig_fft) * highpass_filter) > brightness_threshold, iterations=3)

orig_fft_no_grid = (1 - bright_pixels) * orig_fft # use the inverted Bright Pixels on the original Image-FT
orig_img_no_grid = ifft2(ifftshift(orig_fft_no_grid)).real # revert the FT

thresh = filters.threshold_otsu(orig_img_no_grid)
print("Threshold: %f" % thresh)
holes = morphology.binary_fill_holes(orig_img_no_grid < thresh) # mark corns in b/w-Picture
img_opened = morphology.binary_opening(holes, iterations=2) # remove Noise-Corns
img_eroded = morphology.binary_erosion(img_opened, iterations=4) # needed cause some peppercorns touch the Image-Borders

dist_trans = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(img_eroded)
local_max = feature.peak_local_max(dist_trans, min_distance=7)
local_max_mask = np.zeros(dist_trans.shape, dtype=bool)
local_max_mask[tuple(local_max.T)] = True
labels = watershed(-dist_trans, measure.label(local_max_mask), mask=img_eroded) # separate merged corns
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, nrows=3, figsize=(30,20))
ax[0][0].set_title("Original")
ax[0][0].imshow(orig_img)
ax[0][1].set_title("Original Log-Fourier")
ax[0][1].imshow(orig_fft_log)
ax[0][2].set_title("Noise-Filtered")
ax[0][2].imshow(orig_img_filtered)
ax[0][3].set_title("Filtered Log-Fourier")
ax[0][3].imshow(fourier_spectrum_to_log_spectrum(fftshift(fft2(orig_img_filtered))))
ax[1][0].set_title("Highpass-Filter inverted")
ax[1][0].imshow(highpass_filter)
ax[1][1].set_title("Bright Pixels w/o Center")
ax[1][1].imshow(bright_pixels)
ax[1][2].set_title("No-Grid Fourier")
ax[1][2].imshow(fourier_spectrum_to_log_spectrum(orig_fft_no_grid))
ax[1][3].set_title("No-Grid")
ax[1][3].imshow(orig_img_no_grid)
ax[2][0].set_title("Filled Holes")
ax[2][0].imshow(holes)
ax[2][1].set_title("Opened Image after Holes")
ax[2][1].imshow(img_opened)
ax[2][2].set_title("Eroded after Opening")
ax[2][2].imshow(img_eroded)
ax[2][3].set_title("Watershed Transform")
ax[2][3].imshow(color.label2rgb(labels, bg_label=0))
print("Number of Peppercorns: %d" % labels.max())
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how robust it is, because this took some fiddling with the parameters, but here's a result using gaussian blur and local extrema/non-maximum suppression.

I think there are 110 corns. Might be 111.

```
0. invert (objects white)
1. gaussian blur
2a. threshold for absolute response, just high enough to not pick up any background
2b. NMS via `dilate(blurred) == blurred`, dilation radius = NMS radius, roundish kernel is better than square
3. logical `and`
4. cosmetics (dilate the peaks to make them fat)
```

I prototyped this with something called "imageplay", which is abandoned software based on parts of opencv 2.x, so the pipeline/graph I described is pretty much what's there (no code). Notably many peaks are fatter than minimum because this wasn't strictly equality. That thing doesn't have that. I had to mark a range of "0.00 to 0.00".

[image: output]

Comment: Really Thank You! Im working on this for 3 Full days and i managed to solve it today. This thing makes really fun to me, but its hard to learn in the beginning i assume. 110 is the right answer (our lecturer told it us)